# Scrollview style height not making any difference

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why does this code create a Scrollview of width 100, but with an unlimited height? Am I missing something obvious? Changing the height value doesn't change anything.

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (<ScrollView style={{ width: 100, height: 0, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>);
}
```